# Excluding rows from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an app and am writing functionality where you search for a user based on different criteria and distance, however if that user has previously blocked you then you should not be able to see them in the results. I have 3 tables involved in this query:  users, zip codes, blocks.  Here is what I have so far, unfortunately it's returning zero results.  It should actually return 101 rows based on the test data.

Users Table

```
> +----------+---------+-----------+
|username  |zipcode  |birthdate  |
+----------+---------+-----------+
|tester55  |72758    |1999-09-09 |
+----------+---------+-----------+
|tester86  |60608    |1983-05-10 |
+----------+---------+-----------+
|iosuser5  |10011    |1975-12-19 |
+----------+---------+-----------+

Blocks table
+----------+---------+-----------+
|blocker   |blockeduser
+----------+---------+-----------+
|tester86  |tester55 |          |
+----------+---------+-----------+
|iosuser5  |tester55 |         |
+----------+---------+-----------+

Zip Code table
+----------+---------+-----------+
|zipcode   |city
+----------+---------+-----------+
|72758     |Rogers   |          |
+----------+---------+-----------+
|60608     |Chicago  |         |
+----------+---------+-----------+
SELECT
zipcodes.zip,
zipcodes.city,
zipcodes.state,
users.*,
YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - YEAR(users.birthdate) -(
    RIGHT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 5) < RIGHT(users.birthdate, 5)
) AS age, blocks.blockeduser, blocks.blocker,
center.seekingdistance,
(
    3959 * ACOS(
        COS(RADIANS(zipcodes.latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(center.latitude)) * COS(
            RADIANS(zipcodes.longitude) - RADIANS(center.longitude)
        ) + SIN(RADIANS(zipcodes.latitude)) * SIN(RADIANS(center.latitude))
    )
) AS distance
FROM
    (
        (
        SELECT
            users.username,
            users.zip,
            users.seekingdistance,
            users.seekingGender AS wantgender,
            users.seekingrace AS wantrace,
            users.seekingmarital AS wantmarital,
            users.seekingminage AS wantminage,
            users.seekingmaxage AS wantmaxage,
            users.seekingminheight AS wantminheight,
            users.seekingmaxheight AS wantmaxheight,
            users.seekingbodytype AS wantbodytype,
            users.seekingreligion AS wantreligion,
            users.seekingeducation AS wanteducation,
            users.seekingoccupation AS wantoccupation,
            users.seekingpolitics AS wantpolitics,
            users.seekingkids AS havekids,
            users.seekingwantkids AS wantwantkids,
            users.seekingdrink AS wantdrinker,
            users.seekingsmoke AS wantsmoker,
            users.gender AS mygender,
            zipcodes.latitude,
            zipcodes.longitude
        FROM
            (
                users
            JOIN zipcodes ON users.zip = zipcodes.zip
            )
        WHERE
            (username = 'tester55')
    ) center,
    zipcodes, blocks
    )
INNER JOIN users ON zipcodes.zip = users.zip
WHERE
    (
        users.username <> 'tester55' AND users.birthdate >= DATE_SUB(
            NOW(), INTERVAL wantmaxage YEAR) AND users.birthdate <= DATE_SUB(
                NOW(), INTERVAL wantminage YEAR) 
            ) AND NOT IN (SELECT blocks.blocker from blocks INNER JOIN users on users.username = blocks.blocker WHERE blocks.blockeduser = "tester55" and blocks.blocker = "tester86")
        HAVING
            (
                distance < center.seekingdistance
            ) 
        ORDER BY
            distance
```

I'd appreciate any help.  I'm stumped on how to move forward.

Comment: What's the point of LIKE here? And I see no test data

Comment: @Strawberry, I didn't include the test data but will update with examples if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

and WHAT is not in?

```
 AND ?????? NOT IN (
  SELECT blocks.blocker
  FROM blocks
  INNER JOIN users ON users.username = blocks.blocker
  WHERE blocks.blockeduser = "tester55"
   AND blocks.blocker = "tester86"
  )
```

I suspect that the immediate issue is thet you are not comparing anything in particular to the "in list". So at a large guess I suggest something like the following:

```
SELECT zipcodes.zip
 , zipcodes.city
 ...
FROM (
 (
  SELECT users.username
   , users.zip
   , users.seekingdistance
   ...
   , zipcodes.latitude
   , zipcodes.longitude
  FROM (
   users INNER JOIN zipcodes ON users.zip = zipcodes.zip
   )
  WHERE (username = 'tester55')
  ) center
 , zipcodes                                          -- is this a cross join ???
 , blocks                                            -- is this another cross join ??
 )
INNER JOIN users ON zipcodes.zip = users.zip
WHERE (
  users.username <> 'tester55'
  AND users.gender = wantgender
  ...
  AND wantminheight <= users.height
  AND wantmaxheight >= users.height
  AND users.birthdate >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL wantmaxage YEAR)
  AND users.birthdate <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL wantminage YEAR)
  )
 AND blocks.blocker NOT IN (                                       -- change here
  SELECT blocks.blocker
  FROM blocks
  INNER JOIN users ON users.username = blocks.blocker
  WHERE blocks.blockeduser = "tester55"
   AND blocks.blocker = "tester86"
  )
HAVING (distance < center.seekingdistance)
ORDER BY distance
```

I truly dislike cross joins that depend purely on a comma - it's a recipe for nightmarish debugging. If there are intended cross joins, then use "CROSS JOIN"

Comment: "it doesn't work" does not assist me help you. e.g. did smoke emit from the keyboard and the screen go bright green? (i.e. how did it not work? can you be much more specific please). Did you include "cross join"...  I don't even know what query you actually executed. What is in the zipcodes table?

Comment: My apologies. It returned the same results from my original query that I posted. The zip codes table has a list of zip codes.